# Generating function for number of $1$'s used to write $0$ to $n$ in base $10$?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I am looking to find a generating function that will answer the question "how many $1$'s are used to write the sequence of numbers from $0$ to $n$ in base $10$".

For example, to write the number from $0$ to $10$, there are $2$ numbers with a $1$ digit: $1$ and $10$.

If the generating function is $F$, then the coefficient of $x^10$ in $F(10)$ should be $2$. Hopefully this has made it clear what I am seeking.

I found that there exists an entry for this sequence on OEIS([A094798](http://oeis.org/A094798)), which also lists a generating function(at least, that's what I assumed the "g.f" meant. However, it appears the generating function is recursive, which doesn't make sense to me.

My question boils down to this: ***Are recursive generating functions useful? How can we extract the coefficients from such a function?***

The recursive g.f. is making think that it's either incorrect, or not-useful for finding coefficients.

I'm new to all this, so any help, guidance, resources, etc would be helpful as well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "how many 1's are used to write the sequence of numbers from 0 to n": This sentence is ambiguous. In particular, do you mean that you use base 10 numeration system ? You should give examples for being sure to be properly understood.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question. If it's still not clear, let me know and I'll edit again.

Comment: Should the coefficient of $x^{11}$ be $3$ or $4$? In one place, you ask "how many $1$'s are used", and in another you count the "numbers with a $1$ digit".

Comment: @robjohn, when I said "numbers with a 1 digit" it just so happened that each of those had a single 1 in them. I didn't intend on it being unclear, but to answer your question, the coefficient should be 4, [11, 10, 1]. Another way to word it would be: If you're typing the numbers 0 to n on a computer, how many times would you press the "1" key. Hopefully that's clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g_k(x)$ be the generating function for numbers that have 1 in the $k$'th digit,
so for $|x|<1$ we have
$$g_0(x)=x+x^{11}+x^{21}+\ldots=\frac{x}{1-x^{10}},$$
and
$$g_1(x)=(x^{10}+\ldots +x^{19})+(x^{110}+\ldots + x^{119})+\ldots =
\frac{x^{10}(1-x^{10})}{(1-x)(1-x^{100})}\,.
$$
Similarly,
$$g_k(x)=\frac{x^{10^k}(1-x^{10^k})}{(1-x)(1-x^{10^{k+1}})}\,.$$
Finally,  the $n$th coefficient of $$ G(x)=\sum_{k \ge 0} g_k(x)$$
counts the number of ones in the decimal expansion of $n$, so the function you want is $$F(x)=\frac{G(x)}{1-x} \,.$$

Answer (score 4):

Many generating functions simply encode an existing algorithm as a power series. Here the algorithm is recursive:

Count the number of 1's in 0 to 9

Count the number of 1's in 0 to 99

Count the number of 1's in 0 to 999

And you can have a thought about what is the recursive relationship between steps. Should be something like

\begin{align}
f(999) &= 10 * f(99) + 100 \\
f(99) &= 10 * f(9) + 10 \\
f(9) &= 10 * f(0) + 1
\end{align}

So $f(9) = 1, f(99) = 20$ and $f(999) = 300$

The generating function encodes all of the recursive relationships between $f(n)$ and $f(10n + k)$. Specifically, $g(x)$ is the generating function for $f(n)$ and $g(x^{10})$ is the generating function for $f(10n)$. I'm bringing this up because I want to emphasize that generating functions are not magical, they're often literally just recurrence relations just encoded as rational functions and *in particular* computing the sequence from the generating function is just as hard/just as easy as computing the recurrence(s) explicitly.

You can use it like this (in SageMath):

```
g(x) = 0
for i in range(3):
    g(x) = x/((1-x)*(1-x^10)) + ((1-x^10)/(1-x))^2*g(x^10)
g(x).series(x, 1000).coefficients(sparse=False)
```

Each time we update $g(x)$, it becomes up to the next power of $10$.

Note: the OEIS page has an incorrect formula for $g(x)$, it should be $1 - x^{10}$ not $(1 - x)^{10}$. If someone has an account they should edit this.

Comment: I have proposed the [fix to OEIS](https://oeis.org/draft/A094798), waiting for approval.